# Default UIView width is 768 in UIViewController iPad Landscape mode?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I create a Storyboard with a UIViewController in iPad landscape mode.

I put some logging info in UIViewController and it says the default width of the default view in UIView is 768 but I think the default width for landscape mode should be 1024. ( I use `self.view` in the logging info). Why would this happen?

Answer (score 2):

You must have logged `self.view` in `viewDidLoad`. The main view *always* loads in portrait, even if the current device orientation is landscape (and even if the only orientation supported by the app is landscape). Log `self.view` later in the view controller life cycle (e.g., `viewDidAppear:`) and its dimensions will probably match your expectations.

Also, it doesn't really matter what the orientation is in storyboard, it's just a simulation.

Comment: I logged in one of the IBAction methods. Is it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Oh, I see. The device orientation must be portrait when the action method fires. It doesn't really matter what the orientation is in storyboard, that's just a simulation. In general, the dimensions of views in storyboard are not necessarily the final, on-screen values for views at runtime.

Comment: No I am using landscape mode on the iPad when the app starts. It's like everything is in landscape mode but the view's size is 768 * 1024.